# Reopening last opening last closed tab in tab group closes itself after it reopens in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

When using tab groups, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> reopens the last tab closed and then it disappears immediately and is gone from the history.  This behavior also happens in *Menu bar → History → Reopen Last Closed tab*. It doesn't happen  when I pick last opened tabs that are shown in history menu or when I pick tabs shown in start page with show recently closed tab turned on.

Any suggestions on how to solve this bug?

Comment: I've just tested it and it does in fact exhibit the behavior you describe.  When using Shift-Cmd-T to reopen the last tab it does, then closes it.  This is obviously a bug and it should be reported:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html